# Not able to open Window.Print in iOS / iPhone App and Unable to add documents to Apple Wallet

Tags: progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

We are using https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to create the PWA App for iOS / iPhones

We have two issues - may be similar one

a. On one of the page we have Button to print the page, we have used window.print. This works fine in Browser but no Print Window opens in the iOS App

b. We have the funtionailty to add documents to Apple Wallet, this works fine on Safai Browser, but does not work in the iOS App

Any suggestions to resolve this please.

Solution on how to print and add document to Wallet